# How can I use plain HTML forms instead of Laravel syntax

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use plain HTML in Laravel but I seem to have a route problem and for being new to programming trying to figure it out seems impossible,

I'm getting this error: `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE. http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/posts`

And on Dev Tools Console:
`POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/posts 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Here is my code that someone showed me but still not working...

```
#create.blade#

form action = {{route('`enter code here`')}} method="POST"
       
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="title">Title</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Body</label>
            <input class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment">  </input>
            <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
```

I'm not sure if you can even use normal HTML with Laravel and I'm not sure how one would start to route them correctly

Comment: Here is my #PostsController.php#

 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=> 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);
        
        $post =new Post;
        $post->title=$request->input('title');
        $post->body=$request->input('body');
        $post->save();

Comment: Could you format your code a little bit ? It's hard to read here

Comment: can you also share your route definition

Comment: my apologies with the messy code, keep on getting errors on how to format the code : ) I will quickly send my route definition

Comment: Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@home');


Route::get('/about', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@about');


Route::get('/services', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@services');


Route::resource('posts', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController');

Comment: sorry i cant get the format right in this comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use any html form in the section you've to just add the form as below that I have added

```
<form action="{{ route('controllername/functionname') }}"  method="POST or GET" > 
         any contents inside your form.
</form>
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I will quickly try this method thank you Hadem

Comment: You're most welcome. sure, try and let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: hi if done it but getting this errors now                                                                                          Route [App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\userLogin\resources\views\posts\create.blade.php)

Comment: You've not added that route in the web.php file, try adding a route and check again. the sample of that route is:        Route::get('properties/create', [
    'as' => 'properties.create',
    'uses' => 'propertiesController@create'
  ]);

Comment: hi Hadem I'm still not getting this issue sorted when I use your code Im still not getting a post to the    public function store(Request $request)  when you said I must enter the code above with my inputs, the Controllername is that my PostsController? becase that is where it will store my post and  what function name do you refer to ?

Comment: i got it fixed, your solution worked thank you so much I didn't  route my path correctly, I cant upvote your comment any idea why ?

Comment: You're welcome bro, the Controller name is the actually the class name that you create when creating your controller via php artisan make:controller and the function name is the method inside that class. I hope that I have got you in this.

Comment: that is great to hear that, try on there is a lot to learn and I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide http method type and a valid csdrf field. Example assuming your route is defined as 'put' in your api.php/admin.php file.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('your-route-name') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PUT')}}
```

Alternatively, you can use the newer laravel convention

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')

    ...
</form>
```

More at the docs: [Method field](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#method-field)

By the way, try not to use blade form directives such as `Form::open`, they are mostly deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: hi your method worked, just one question I'm trying to route it to my PostsController                   public function store(Request $request)  how can i do that ?

Comment: First define your route in index.php file: ```Route::put('your-desired-route', 'PostsController@store')->name('your-route-name');```. Then in the form  `action="{{ route('your-route-name') }}"`

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, please consider upvoting/marking as answer.

Comment: the FormBuilder/HtmlBuilder is its own package maintained by the LaravelCollective, so not deprecated if you use the one from them and not `illuminate\html` (which is abandoned)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ResourceController, you can use this.

```
<form action="{{ route('enter code here') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('PUT')
```

If you use Controller (simple), you can use this.

```
<form action="{{ route('enter code here') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
```